# in Wordpress, alter media uploading method to add custom processing

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails, media

What I want to do is display thumbnail images of photographs (the 150x150 images) in a page organized by the date the picture was **taken**.

I looked at the files uploaded, and the original (unchanged, large) image has the original date, but the thumbnails are dated at the date of the **upload**. I imagine there must be some way of post-processing the thumbnails to change their date to the original date, or to add some tag containing the date?

Answer (score 1):

You can use touch:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php

So after the thumb is created use touch to set the file dates/times to the ones of the original file.

P.S. original file time with for example filectime()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php

Comment: Thanks, this partly answers my question - however it does not tell me where or how to add in the command in question. I was thinking along the lines of adding the process on to the file upload process, or possibly a batch treatment of all files.